# The way of accessing and setting server-side variable with client-side

Tags: javascript, validation, xpages, ssjs

I have an XPage which uses client-side validation. If validation fails it gives the user an `alert` message and won't permit proccess server-side stuff. The problem I've encountered is being unable to "assign" server-side variables with client-side. For example, consider I have an xp input field like this:

```
<xp:inputText 
  styleClass="doc_field_textinput" id="input_part_title" type="text" size="40" 
  disableClientSideValidation="true" >
</xp:inputText>
```

And I use a button in order to validate and if validation succeeds - save this:

```
<xp:button id="save_part_btn" value="+Add this" style="float:right;">
             <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:

                    var estdoc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByUNID(doc_source.getDocument().getParentDocumentUNID())
                    var estPartdoc:NotesDocument=estdoc.getParentDatabase().createDocument()

                    estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Form','Estimate_Cost_Part')
                    estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Predoc',estdoc.getUniversalID())
                    estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('$OSN_IsSaved','1')

                    estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Title', getComponent('input_part_title').getValue())

                    }]]>
            </xp:this.action>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[ 
                var result = "";
                var wholeResult = true;

                function isStringEmpty(string2Check) 
                {
                    return string2Check == "" || string2Check[0] == " ";
                }

                if(isStringEmpty(document.getElementById("#{id:input_part_title}").value)) 
                {
                    wholeResult = false;
                    result += 'The field cannot be empty!'
                }

                result = result.replace(/\n$/, "")

                if(!wholeResult) 
                {
                    alert(result)
                }

                return wholeResult;

                ]]>
                </xp:this.script>
             </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Unfortunatly, the `input_part_title` on the **server-side** is always **null**, 
under any circumstances, whereas `document.getElementById("#{id:input_part_title}").value` works so well, and really works the way it's expected. I wish I could add the same line of code to my Server-Side, but I can't because `document` is an unknown property on the server side. Is there any way I can somehow assign `input_part_title` to a value from client-side?

Comment: Have you tried *getSubmittedValue* instead of *getValue*?

Comment: Yup, tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use the `value` property of the component to bind it to some server-side element, e.g. a field on a dominoDocument datasource or a `viewScope` variable. You can then reference.

An alternative is to use `getComponent("input_part_title").getValue()`.

Attaching a validator to the component will ensure validation occurs during the Process Validations phase on the server. If you have non-text input components (e.g. to take a number), that phase also runs converter checks and aborts accordingly. That will then abort processing, so your code in the button's eventHandler's `action` property won't run at all. It will also handle returning the error message to the browser (programmatically you'd need to look at `facesContext.addMessage()` as well as highlighting the component as being invalid (`getComponent.setValid(false)`). The validator handles all of that for you.

Comment: Yes I see, using `viewScope` seems to solve the problem. So I add into xp:inputText  value property, like this `value="{viewScope.part_title}"` How do I later access and change `input_part_title` property on the client-side?

Comment: Client-side, you need to access the HTML component in standard JavaScript handling of HTML forms. Server-side, binding it to a `dominoDocument` or `viewScope` variable allows you to access from the datasource (which is basically a Java object scoped to the XPage). This avoids iterating the component tree, which is costly for performance and can only get the closest component with that name - in the case of Custom Controls and Repeat Controls, the same ID can be used multiple times.